# "Through using" or "through use of"?

Tags: grammar

"Phishing entails collecting victim information through using social engineering."

Is this correct? It sounds better to use "through use of" to my ears, but would that be more correct?

I also considered "by using," but I prefer to use "through" as it seems to imply that "using social engineering" was *the* method used rather than simply a part of the process.

Comment: 4 -ing in one sentence feels a bit much.

Comment: Try dropping the word `using` entirely, you'll find the sentence reads much better.

Answer (score 1):

There is no need to use either `using` or `use of`. "Through" inherently implies the same.

It should simply be:

> Phishing entails collecting victim information through social
> engineering.